# How can we use @types/bootbox and @types/jquery?

Tags: angular, typescript

How can we use @types/bootbox and @types/jquery in angular 4 project?
I did something like this

```
npm install @types/bootbox
```

and  in my code I am doing something like this

```
import * as bootbox from 'bootbox'.
```

**I am getting this Error**
@types/bootbox/index.d.ts (96,41): Generic type 'JQuery' requires 2 type argument(s).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just install both of them ([@types/bootbox](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/bootbox), [@types/jquery](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/jquery)) with NPM:

```
npm install --save-dev @types/bootbox
npm install --save-dev @types/jquery
```

Comment: I am getting a lot of errors after adding this 

ERROR in /Users/mantu.nigam/Documents/PROJECTS/NGOSS2/NGOSS-Angular2_UI/node_modules/@types/jquery/index.d.ts (2366,129): Generic type 'JQuery<TElement, HTMLElement>' requires 2 type argument(s).

ERROR in /Users/mantu.nigam/Documents/PROJECTS/NGOSS2/NGOSS-Angular2_UI/node_modules/@types/jquery/index.d.ts (2379,78): Generic type 'JQuery<TElement, HTMLElement>' requires 2 type argument(s).

Comment: I am using this.
import * as bootbox from 'bootbox'

Comment: @MantuNigam This information should be in your question, not in the comments.

Comment: Looks like a version conflict with the JQuery types